# Battleships game: how can I check the surroundings of ships and count the number of ships on the board?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, coordinates

I need to write a program that takes user input for the number of ships on a battleships board, and the size of the board (which is always square - so if size = 5 the board is 5x5). Then the program takes the board row by row and puts it into a bi-dimensional array.

Where I am stuck is the program then must validate if the board entered by the user is correct. This is both in terms of boats not being allowed to touch (even diagonally) and the number of boats being correct. This program then returns a statement either saying the board is correct or it is not.

This is the code I have so far:

```
// This checks whether the boat is diagonal, horizontal or just length 1

static boolean checkType(int[][] board, int size) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
                if (board[x][y] == 1) {
                    if (board[x + 1][y] == 1) {
                        horizontalBoat(board, size, x, y);
                    } else if (board[x][y + 1] == 1) {
                        verticalBoat(board, size, x, y);
                    } else singleBoat(board, size, x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }

/* Then for example the boat is horizontal, it passes the initial point through this 
method. What I have tried to do is for the for loop to continue until it has passed 
through all the points that the boat is at. Then it passes values into the second for 
loop which basically tries to check that the square around the ship on the board is all 
0s (as boats are also not allowed to touch diagonally) - hence why I have passed the position 
before the first 1 and the position after the last 1 of the boat into it. However for some 
reason the for statement won't loop. 
*/

 static boolean horizontalBoat(int[][] board, int size, int x, int y) {
        for (int c = x; c < size; ) {
            if (board[c][y] == 1) {
                c++;
            } else {
                int lastPositionX = c;
                if (((board[x - 1][y]) == 0) && ((board[x + 1][y]) == 0)) {
                    for (int firstPositionX = (x - 1); firstPositionX <= lastPositionX; firstPositionX++) {
                        if ((board[firstPositionX][y + 1] == 0) && (board[firstPositionX][y - 1] == 0)){
                        return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

// For context, this part of the code stores the board through user input. This part works.

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ships_num;
        Scanner sc;
        int size;
        int[][] board;

        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of boats. The max is 10  ");
            ships_num = sc.nextInt();
        } while (ships_num > 10);
        System.out.println("Number of boats " + ships_num);

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter the size of the board. The max is 20");
            size = sc.nextInt();
        } while (size > 20);
        System.out.println("El tamano del tablero: " + size);

        board = new int[size][size];

        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the values of each row of the board, starting with"
  +"the first. Enter 1 to represent a ship and 0 to represent water.");
            String temp = sc.next();
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                board[x][y] = temp.charAt(x);
            }
        }
```

Also, I want to try to create an int ships_num_check which will add one every time a boat is finished, so at the end I can compare this to the number of boats there is supposed to be. However I am not sure how I can do this across methods due to scope?

Comment: Put the code you posted aside and create a test program where you hard code a valid input grid and an invalid input grid.  Once you get your validation logic working, then add the `Scanner` code back in.  Break your code into small (10 lines or less) testable methods.  One approach could be to scan the input grid once and create an array of ship coordinate points.  You can then process the coordinate array, looking for ships that touch.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Hi Gilbert, sorry I am new to coding, but I am not really sure what you mean by that. Would you be able to show in example in code? I am struggling with how I can get the code to recognise what is a boat, and what is one boat touching another. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to create a test program. This code is based on the following assumptions:

1. A ship can be any length from one to the width and height of the input grid.
2. A ship can be horizontally, vertically, or diagonally placed.
3. No two ships can touch horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.

The result should be:

```
true
false
```

Here's the test bed code. Feel free to add as many input grids as you wish to test your code:

```
public class BattleshipTesting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Valid grid
        int numberOfShips1 = 4;
        int[][] inputGrid1 = { { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 } };
        System.out.println(verifyGrid(numberOfShips1, inputGrid1));
        
        // Invalid grid
        int numberOfShips2 = 5;
        int[][] inputGrid2 = { { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                            { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, 
                            { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 } };
        System.out.println(verifyGrid(numberOfShips2, inputGrid2));
    }
    
    public static boolean verifyGrid(int numberOfShips, int[][] inputGrid) {
        // Here's where your testing logic goes
        return true;
    }

}
```

When you have a working `verifyGrid` method, then you can add your `Scanner` code back in.

Break your code into small (10 lines or less) testable methods.